# webview crashes on Mac OS 10.7 (Not on 10.8)

Tags: cocoa, webview

I am using webview to load webpage, it crashes on 10.7 only, it works fine on 10.8.I am not using any javascript call in code.

any guess?

FYI, same URL is working fine is safari(10.7).

Only diff I see,
10.8: webkit version 8536
10.7.5: webkit version 7534.57

```
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff9901dbca __psynch_cvwait + 10
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff972ab274 _pthread_cond_wait + 840
2   com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8ec0ffbc -[NSViewHierarchyLock     _lockForWriting:handler:] + 547
3   com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8ec0af46 -[NSView setFrameSize:] + 350
4   com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8ece5c41 -[NSControl setFrameSize:] + 83
5   com.apple.WebCore               0x00007fff97e390d8    WebCore::ScrollView::platformSetContentsSize() + 66
6   com.apple.WebCore               0x00007fff97e39066 WebCore::ScrollView::setContentsSize(WebCore::IntSize const&) + 86
7   com.apple.WebCore               0x00007fff97e38e7e WebCore::FrameView::setContentsSize(WebCore::IntSize const&) + 56
8   com.apple.WebCore               0x00007fff97eacf2e WebCore::FrameView::adjustViewSize() + 164
9   com.apple.WebCore               0x00007fff97e9021f WebCore::FrameView::layout(bool) + 2071
10  com.apple.WebCore               0x00007fff97e8f940 WebCore::Document::updateLayoutIgnorePendingStylesheets() + 110
11  com.apple.WebCore               0x00007fff9811dd17 WebCore::Element::offsetHeight() +    21
12  com.apple.WebCore               0x00007fff9811dce1 WebCore::jsElementOffsetHeight(JSC::ExecState*, JSC::JSValue, JSC::Identifier const&) + 17
13  com.apple.JavaScriptCore        0x00007fff935476e4 JSC::JSValue::get(JSC::ExecState*, JSC::Identifier const&, JSC::PropertySlot&) const + 388
14  com.apple.JavaScriptCore        0x00007fff93547492 cti_op_get_by_id + 98
15  ???                             0x00004e3263a57cfa 0 + 85978327121146
16  com.apple.JavaScriptCore        0x00007fff93534c1a JSC::Interpreter::executeCall(JSC::ExecState*, JSC::JSObject*, JSC::CallType, JSC::CallData const&, JSC::JSValue, JSC::ArgList const&) + 826
17  com.apple.JavaScriptCore        0x00007fff935348cd JSC::call(JSC::ExecState*, JSC::JSValue, JSC::CallType, JSC::CallData const&, JSC::JSValue, JSC::ArgList const&) + 45
18  com.apple.WebCore               0x00007fff97f1315d WebCore::JSEventListener::handleEvent(WebCore::ScriptExecutionContext*, WebCore::Event*) + 879
19  com.apple.WebCore               0x00007fff97f12d64 WebCore::EventTarget::fireEventListeners(WebCore::Event*, WebCore::EventTargetData*, WTF::Vector<WebCore::RegisteredEventListener, 1ul>&) + 494
20  com.apple.WebCore               0x00007fff97e37623 WebCore::EventTarget::fireEventListeners(WebCore::Event*) + 85
21  com.apple.WebCore               0x00007fff97e37710 WebCore::Node::handleLocalEvents(WebCore::Event*) + 180
22  com.apple.WebCore               0x00007fff97e36d94 WebCore::EventDispatcher::dispatchEvent(WTF::PassRefPtr<WebCore::Event>) + 832
23  com.apple.WebCore               0x00007fff97e36a18 WebCore::EventDispatchMediator::dispatchEvent(WebCore::EventDispatcher*) const + 40
24  com.apple.WebCore               0x00007fff97e36919 WebCore::EventDispatcher::dispatchEvent(WebCore::Node*, WebCore::EventDispatchMediator const&) + 41
25  com.apple.WebCore               0x00007fff97e3688f WebCore::Node::dispatchEvent(WTF::PassRefPtr<WebCore::Event>) + 55
26  com.apple.WebCore               0x00007fff97e82918 WebCore::Document::finishedParsing() + 156
27  com.apple.WebCore               0x00007fff97e3b411 WebCore::HTMLDocumentParser::prepareToStopParsing() + 167
28  com.apple.WebCore               0x00007fff97e2a995 WebCore::DocumentWriter::endIfNotLoadingMainResource() + 107
29  com.apple.WebCore               0x00007fff97edf502 WebCore::FrameLoader::finishedLoading() + 72
30  com.apple.WebCore               0x00007fff97edf423 WebCore::MainResourceLoader::didFinishLoading(double) + 133
31  com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff8e2ea63e ___NSURLConnectionDidFinishLoading_block_invoke_1 + 122
```

Crash report says, it crashed in thread 0 which is above
Updated another thread dump,

```
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff9901d82a __kill + 10
1   coop.plausible.CrashReporter    0x0000000100c91cfa fatal_signal_handler + 124
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff972fbcfa _sigtramp + 26
3   com.apple.WebCore               0x00007fff97e13f7c WebCore::TimerBase::setNextFireTime(double) + 142
4   com.apple.WebCore               0x00007fff97e8fa46 WebCore::FrameView::layout(bool) + 62
5   com.apple.WebKit                0x00007fff94c36528 -[WebHTMLView layoutToMinimumPageWidth:height:maximumPageWidth:adjustingViewSize:] + 264
6   com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8f245c75 -[NSView _layoutSubtreeHeedingRecursionGuard:] + 105
7   com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8ec0b414 __NSViewRecursionHelper + 25
8   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff97bddcb4 CFArrayApplyFunction + 68
9   com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8f245e67 -[NSView _layoutSubtreeHeedingRecursionGuard:] + 603
10  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8ec0b414 __NSViewRecursionHelper + 25
11  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff97bddcb4 CFArrayApplyFunction + 68
12  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8f245e67 -[NSView _layoutSubtreeHeedingRecursionGuard:] + 603
13  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8ec0b414 __NSViewRecursionHelper + 25
14  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff97bddcb4 CFArrayApplyFunction + 68
15  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8f245e67 -[NSView _layoutSubtreeHeedingRecursionGuard:] + 603
16  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8ec0b414 __NSViewRecursionHelper + 25
17  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff97bddcb4 CFArrayApplyFunction + 68
18  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8f245e67 -[NSView _layoutSubtreeHeedingRecursionGuard:] + 603
19  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8ec0b414 __NSViewRecursionHelper + 25
20  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff97bddcb4 CFArrayApplyFunction + 68
21  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8f245e67 -[NSView _layoutSubtreeHeedingRecursionGuard:] + 603
22  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8ec0b414 __NSViewRecursionHelper + 25
23  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff97bddcb4 CFArrayApplyFunction + 68
24  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8f245e67 -[NSView _layoutSubtreeHeedingRecursionGuard:] + 603
25  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8ec0b414 __NSViewRecursionHelper + 25
26  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff97bddcb4 CFArrayApplyFunction + 68
27  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8f245e67 -[NSView _layoutSubtreeHeedingRecursionGuard:] + 603
28  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8ec0b414 __NSViewRecursionHelper + 25
29  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff97bddcb4 CFArrayApplyFunction + 68
30  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8f245e67 -[NSView _layoutSubtreeHeedingRecursionGuard:] + 603
31  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8f245bd9 -[NSView layoutSubtreeIfNeeded] + 556
32  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8f3c0c9a -[NSWindow(NSConstraintBasedLayout) layoutIfNeeded] + 190
33  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8ec08735 -[NSView _sendViewWillDrawInRect:clipRootView:suppressRecursion:] + 54
34  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8edb5f10 -[NSView(NSLayerKitGlue) _drawViewBackingLayer:inContext:drawingHandler:] + 998
35  com.apple.QuartzCore            0x00007fff943d60dc -[CALayer drawInContext:] + 145
36  com.apple.QuartzCore            0x00007fff943d5225 CABackingStoreUpdate_ + 3221
37  com.apple.QuartzCore            0x00007fff943d413a CA::Layer::display_() + 1086
38  com.apple.QuartzCore            0x00007fff943cc00a CA::Layer::display_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 560
39  com.apple.QuartzCore            0x00007fff943cafbf CA::Context::commit_transaction(CA::Transaction*) + 319
40  com.apple.QuartzCore            0x00007fff943cad3c CA::Transaction::commit() + 274
41  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff8edfffd1 -[NSUIHeartBeat _heartBeatThread:] + 1397
42  com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff8e2dc72a -[NSThread main] + 68
43  com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff8e2dc6a2 __NSThread__main__ + 1575
```

Comment: The above stack trace does not show a crash. That's simply showing a thread waiting for a lock to become unlocked. Is anything written to the console when the crash occurs? Which SDK have you selected in your target in Xcode? If you're not building against the 10.7 (or earlier) SDK, that might cause a problem on 10.7.

Comment: I am using UseNotifications on 10.8 onwards, so require to build on 10.8 sdk. Is there a way to build using 10.7sdk & use user notification?